# I am trying to make this code tail recursive by adding a parameter but I am not 100% sure how to implment the 1 + recusrive call section

Tags: c++

I need to make this tail recursive by adding a parameter but I am not sure the first step to take.

```
int countVal (int A[], int size, int val)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (A[size - 1] == val)
        return 1 + countVal(A, size-1, val);
    else
        return countVal(A, size - 1, val);
}
```

Comment: What's the issue here? This already works.

Comment: In this form it is not considered tail recursive due to the 1 + countVal() call. I need to convert it to make it tail recursive.

Answer (score 3):

The added parameter should accumulate the result, and when recursion terminates you return the accumulated result rather than the base value.
In this case, you can give the base value as a default parameter value:

```
int countVal (int A[], int size, int val, int accumulator = 0)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return accumulator;
    else if (A[size - 1] == val)
        return countVal(A, size - 1, val, accumulator + 1);
    else
        return countVal(A, size - 1, val, accumulator);
}
```

but it's also common to use a separate (and hidden) helper function.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I've been stuck on this for several hours. The notes given she used Lisp and It made it really confusing. Thanks again.